# How to improve performance on multiple identical video tags that play simultaneously

Tags: html, css, performance, video, optimization

I'm working on a little project where i'm using webms with alpha as textures for flip-cards (using `backface-visibility: hidden` and css animations)

This is the code i'm using once i need the animations to start

```
var vids = document.querySelectorAll("video");
for (var i = 0; i < vids.length; i++) {
    vids[i].play();
    cards[i].classList.remove('flip');
    cards[i].classList.add('fade');
    await sleep(10);
}
```

This works great for up to 4-5 cards, however i'd like to play up to 13 of those cards, doing so right now makes half of the videos drop most of the frames (unusable).

All `<video/>` tags have the same 1-2mb webm source and it is intended to only run locally and only in chromium/chrome.

I was wondering if there is a way to "instance" the video as is usually done with geometry in games.

I suppose it would be possible to decode this once and then use a canvas to render the same video multiple times, but right now i'm looking for a non-canvas solution. If there is such a thing.

I've already tried preloading the video hoping that caching it would improve performance

```
<link rel="preload" as="video" href="vid.webm">
```

But this isn't really changing anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up replacing every "instance" of my video with a canvas, performance is stellar, eventhough i'm drawing to separate canvases. This way you can easily run tens of instances

The code below is just for illustration, this can of course be written much better.
Also if you happen to need video with transparency, make sure you clear the canvas every frame using `ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);` otherwise you'll be drawing over your previous images.

```js
var canvas1 = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas2');
var canvas3 = document.getElementById('canvas3');
var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
var ctx3 = canvas3.getContext('2d');
var video = document.getElementById('video');

canvas1.width = 100;
canvas1.height = 100;
canvas2.width = 100;
canvas2.height = 100;
canvas3.width = 100;
canvas3.height = 100;

video.addEventListener('play', function() {
  var $this = this; //cache
  (function loop() {
    if (!$this.paused && !$this.ended) {
      ctx1.drawImage($this, 0, 0, ctx1.canvas.clientWidth, ctx1.canvas.clientHeight);
      ctx2.drawImage($this, 0, 0, ctx2.canvas.clientWidth, ctx2.canvas.clientHeight);
      ctx3.drawImage($this, 0, 0, ctx3.canvas.clientWidth, ctx3.canvas.clientHeight);
      setTimeout(loop, 1000 / 30); // drawing at 30fps
    }
  })();
}, 0);
```

```css
canvas {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

video {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="theater">
  <video id="video" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Big_Buck_Bunny_small.ogv" controls="false" autoplay muted></video>
  <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas3"></canvas>
</div>
```